# Add and Remove class using jQuery setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to show my image like waving flames. So I thought using two form of layers(flame tongues) and stack same position in same place(behind one in another). Then I tried to hide second flame tongue and show first flame tongue. Then hide second flame tongue and show first one like that. (One hide, another show)

I tried using jquery setInterval But I faced few problems. Sometimes it shows two flames at once in screen. That's weird. Take a look at my code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flame-1 flames-one">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Pfsrdh.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flame-2 flames-two">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EypytyC.png" alt="">
  </div>
<div class="wrapper-img">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/moNtPwG.png" class="wrap-img" alt="">
</div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

.flame-1,
.flame-2,
.wrapper-img,
.show-1,
.show-2{
   position: absolute;
}
/* .flame-1,
.flame-2{
  top:30px;
  display:none;
} */


.flame-1{
 left: 38px;
 top: 32px;

}

.flames-one,
.flames-two{
   display:none;
}

.flame-2{
  left: 67px;
  top: 40px;
}

.flame-2 img{
  width: 190px;
}

.wrapper-img{
   top:220px;
}

.show-1,
.show-2{
  display:block;
}

var $flameOne = $(".flames-one");
setInterval(function(){
    $flameOne.toggleClass("show-1");
}, 300);


var $flameTwo = $(".flames-two");
setInterval(function(){
    $flameTwo.toggleClass("show-1");
}, 500)
```

Any solution?

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/uy43w5qq/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sometimes it shows two flames at once in screen

That's because you have set different intervals for both classes:

```
var $flameOne = $(".flames-one");
setInterval(function(){
    $flameOne.toggleClass("show-1");
}, 300);                           // <-- This


var $flameTwo = $(".flames-two");
setInterval(function(){
    $flameTwo.toggleClass("show-1");
}, 500);                            // <-- And this
```

Making them equal should solve the issue.

To go a step further, you can do both actions in same function:

```
var $flameOne = $(".flames-one");
var $flameTwo = $(".flames-two");
$flameOne.toggleClass("show-1");        // This is to keep one of the flames hidden initially.
setInterval(function(){
    $flameOne.toggleClass("show-1");
    $flameTwo.toggleClass("show-1");
}, 300);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uy43w5qq/2/

Comment: Got it buddy. Is that possible to use css transform with this? Like this example https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/papy1k0w/5/

Comment: I think that's much better than javascript! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution to this issue is to use a single interval to toggle a class on the container, then hide/show the relevant image based on that class. Try this:

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
setInterval(function() {
  $wrapper.toggleClass("alt");
}, 300);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flames,
.wrapper-img,
.show-1,
.show-2 {
  position: absolute;
}

.flames {
  display: none;
}

.flame-1 {
  left: 38px;
  top: 32px;
}

.flame-2 {
  left: 67px;
  top: 40px;
}

.flame-2 img {
  width: 190px;
}

.wrapper-img {
  top: 220px;
}

.wrapper .flame-1 { display: block; }
.wrapper .flame-2 { display: none; }
.wrapper.alt .flame-1 { display: none; }
.wrapper.alt .flame-2 { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flame-1 flames">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Pfsrdh.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="flame-2 flames">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EypytyC.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/moNtPwG.png" class="wrap-img" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one setInterval and keep the current state of the flames.
For example,if your current state is flame one, then move to flame two.

Answer (score 1):

Put flameTwo into `setTimeout()` function. Because initially flame 2 start only after the flame 1 complete. Here is my code

```
var $flameTwo = $(".flames-two");
setTimeout(function() {
 setInterval(function(){
    $flameTwo.toggleClass("show-2");
    }, 300)
}, 300)
```